# Split list into smaller lists based on values?

Tags: python

Say I have a list: `[1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 5, 6, 7, -1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1]`

I want to split this list into using values `-1` or `0, 0` as a delimiter:

`[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [], [3, 2, 1]]`

(Note the empty 3rd list)

How would I achieve this? My current solution is just a trivial loop but I'm wondering if theres a more pythonic solution (using list comprehensions) for delimiters of any length?

Current solution as requested (messy and hacky :P)

```
string = '|'.join([str(x) for x in data]).replace('-1', ',').replace('0|0', ',')
buckets = [x.split('|') if y for x in string.split(',')]
```

Comment: How about posting your solution?

Comment: If creating a string is acceptable (this is very use-case specific) you can use that...

Comment: @mhawke sure... it's pretty trivial though, I don't think it will add much value to the question.

Comment: @VeraWang actually it will add value, because then we can see how you approached it and then either improve that or suggest a whole new approach

Comment: post the loop to us, we can help you improve it. You should make a function with these loop and call it when you need it. It will help you change it easily :)

Comment: Done, I did a little refactoring with @ReutSharabani's suggestion but I think its quite hacky...

Comment: `reduce(lambda (l, l2), v: (l, l2+[v]) if v != -1 else (l+[l2], []), l, ([], []))` for single items will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's not trivial, but you can done it like this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 5, 6, 7, -1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1]

my_list = ','.join(map(str, my_list))
my_list = [x.split(',') for y in my_list.split('0,0,') for x in y.split(',-1,')]
my_list = [map(int, x) if x != [''] else [] for x in my_list]
```

Comment: Where does the `l` in  `map(str, l)` come from? Should it be `my_list` instead?

Comment: Also I think there might be edge case where value is `''`.

Comment: Yes, it should be `my_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `for loop and check conditions`

**Code:**

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 5, 6, 7, -1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1,-1,0]
output_lst = []
check = 0
sample=[]
for val in lst:
    if val == -1 :
        output_lst.append(sample)
        check = 0
        sample = []
        continue
    if val == 0 :       

        if check ==1 :
            output_lst.append(sample[:-1])
            check = 0
            sample = []
            continue
        check = 1
    sample.append(val)
if check ==1:
    output_lst.append(sample)
print output_lst
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [], [3, 2, 1], [0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

use one iteration for to do it.

```
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 5, 6, 7, -1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1]
data  = ', '.join(map(str, ar))
import re
data = re.split(", -1,| 0, 0,",data)
bucket = []
import ast
for y in data:
    hac = ast.literal_eval("["+y+"]")
    bucket.append(hac)
print bucket
```